# Get image dimensions

Tags: jquery

I think a somehwat simple problem, but i can't find any solutions. I need to get the image dimensions from an image that is not yet loaded, but have no clue how.

I have the following html

```
<a href="http://domain.com/folder/bigImage.jpg" id="someID">
 <img src="http://domain.com/folder/smallImage.jpg">
</a>
```

Now i want to get the image dimensions of the big image, but how?

```
$("#someID").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 image = this.href;
 newImage = new Image();
 newImage.src = image;
 alert(newImage.width);
});
```

or

```
$("#someID").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 image = this.href;
 newImage = new Image();
 newImage.src = image;
 newImage.load(function(){
  alert(newImage.width);
 });
});
```

both don't work

Comment: I'm not sure that approach will work, since JS related to the Dom, and even Image() is just a representation of the a dom element of the type img, not an actual image, so you set the attribute (src) of that dom element, but that doesn't make any difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is a jQuery function so you need a wrapper, and bind it *before* setting the `src`, like this:

```
$("#someID").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var newImage = new Image();
  $(newImage).load(function(){
    alert(this.width);
  });
  newImage.src = this.href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is close; you need to wait for the image to load first, before you can retrieve the dimensions of it.

```
$('#someId').bind('click', function (event) {
  var image = new Image();
  image.onload = function () {
    var height = this.height;
    var width = this.width;

    alert(height + " | " + width);
  }
  image.src = this.href;

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

You can see a working fiddle here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/JsRmU/